# What difference with socket in windows using php?

Tags: php, linux, windows, php-socket

I have wrote one app in php which uses sockets. Suddenly there was a need to run it on windows, before this it was only on linux with no problems.

Currently problem is in `socket_recv` function which is used like `$bytes = @socket_recv($socket, $data, 2048, MSG_DONTWAIT);`. First of all on the windows there isn't any `MSG_DONTWAIT` constant as i get nocite about it. I found a small fix for it like:

```
if (!defined('MSG_DONTWAIT'))
   define('MSG_DONTWAIT', 0x40);
```

Then it says:

```
Warning: socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [0]: The operation completed
successfully.
```

After it i decided to ask may be there is some difference with work with sockets on Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a difference when you create socket in windows as opposed to linux.

Try something like this:

```
<?php

// Init
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 10000;

// On Windows we need to use AF_INET
$domain = (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN' ? AF_INET : AF_UNIX);

// Create socket
if (($sock = socket_create($domain, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

// Bind socket to port
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

// start listening
if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);

?>
```

Comment: by default i use AF_INET

Comment: Same here, I also use AF_INET by default on WAMP server with PHP 5.4